# Windows 10 cannot make outgoing connections

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, firewall

I am using Windows Server 2016 over RDP. I cannot make any outgoing connection: Firefox any URL or IP displays "unable to connect"  (There is no proxy configured). In ping, to any IP address i have "general failiure" to any external or private (internal) IP. curl also shows Operation not permitted.

Testing In wireshark shows packets incoming/outgoing for the rdp but there are no packets appearing for any outgoing connections i initiate.

Output of route print:

```
C:\Windows\system32>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...00 ff a5 18 10 27 ......Windscribe VPN
 18...5e bc ae c9 b9 3b ......VPN Client Adapter - VPN
 16...96 00 00 14 31 66 ......Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter
  8...00 ff 5f f1 6a 9d ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.31.1.1   195.201.11.111     15
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.31.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link    195.201.11.111     16
   195.201.11.111  255.255.255.255         On-link    195.201.11.111    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    195.201.11.111    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    195.201.11.111    271
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 16    271 fe80::/64                On-link
 16    271 fe80::e1a5:f33b:ae7c:b913/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 16    271 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

ipconfig output

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Unknown adapter VPN - VPN Client:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e1a5:f33b:ae7c:b135%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 195.201.11.111
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.31.1.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C08A9A9B-4847-4F78-A940-441E651792D2}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

And here are my Windows Firewall rules output
https://pastebin.com/GWv3kKER

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. The problem was in the end because of one of these programs:

ZPN
TAP windows
Sandboxie
Hola VPN

After uninstalling them I can connect again :)